# Python re findall matching repeating pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse semi-structured text that's of the following format:

```
text = "A. xxxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n\nB. xxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n\nC. xxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n\nD. xxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx"
```

I'd like to have each of these sections as a different group. I'm currently trying to parse with a regular expression that looks for the text between the uppercase letters followed by a period:

```
re.findall(r"([A-Z]\.[\s\S]*?)(?:\n[A-Z]\.|$)", text)
```

However, this only parse parts A and C:

```
['A. xxxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n', 'C. xxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n']
```

How can I modify the regular expression such that the last part of the match is not excluded from future matches?

I can't split by new lines as the number of new lines between the subsections can vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lookahead and (optionally) get rid of of capturing group:

```
>>> print re.findall(r"[A-Z]\.[\s\S]*?(?=\n[A-Z]\.|$)", text)
['A. xxxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n', 'B. xxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n', 'C. xxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx\n\n', 'D. xxxxxx\n\nxxx\n\nxxx']
```

Note use of `(?=\n[A-Z]\.|$)` (zero width lookahead assertion) which only asserts presence of given text without actually matching it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`[A-Z]\.[^.]*(?<![A-Z])`

though this one

`(?m)^[A-Z]\.(?:(?!^[A-Z]\.)[\S\s])*`

https://regex101.com/r/t1R28Q/1

will never fail.